# How to pre-populate a Select?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I would like to pre-populate a *Select* component (from Vuetify.js) with some values.

I use the asynchronous version, where I get selectable data as

```
[
  {
    text: "hello",
    value: {
      type: "word",
      language: "english"
    }
  },
    {
    text: "bonjour",
    value: {
      type: "word",
      language: "french"
    }
  }
]
```

which, upon selection, are stored in `v-model` as an array of objects (the `value` of the proposed selection above).

I would like to pre-populate the search field with some default entries (say, the French one above), to have:

- "bonjour" in the search field
- `{type: "word",language: "french"}` in `v-model`

Is there a way to do that with Vuetify?

Answer (score 0):

`:items` hold the options list.

`v-model` hold the selected options list.

Because your selectable data is not just an array of strings but an array of objects  you should tell vuetify which property is the value and which is the label property in these objects with `item-text`(text) and `item-value`(value.english) attributes.

So vue can match `v-model` against `:items` to find the selected ones.

So to select `english`, your `v-model` should look like :

```
[
   {
     text: "hello",
     value: {
        type: "word",
        language: "english"
    }
]
```

And your select component should have :

```
<v-select ... :item-value="value.language" :item-text="text"></v-select>
```